# Why is my object of type SKTileMapNode not being decoded?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nscoding

In a custom class: `class BoardTileManager:NSObject, NSCoding {` I implement the methods for `NSCoding` as follows:

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(self.mainBoardMap!, forKey: "BoardTileManager_mainBoardMap")
    aCoder.encode(self.tileSelectionBoardMap!, forKey: "BoardTileManager_tileSelectionBoardMap")
    aCoder.encode(self.tileWallingBoardMap!, forKey: "BoardTileManager_tileWallingBoardMap")
    aCoder.encode(self.tileWallingTextures!.wallType.rawValue, forKey: "BoardTileManeger_tileWallingTextures"

}
```

and the complementary init function:

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoardTileManager_mainBoardMap")
    if aDecoder.containsValue(forKey: "BoardTileManager_mainBoardMap") == true {
        print("herro")
    }
    if let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoardTileManager_mainBoardMap") as? SKTileMapNode {
        self.mainBoardMap = data
    }
    if let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoardTileManager_tileSelectionBoardMap") as? SKTileMapNode {
        self.tileSelectionBoardMap = data
    }
    if let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoardTileManager_tileWallingBoardMap") as? SKTileMapNode {
        self.tileWallingBoardMap = data
    }
    if let data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "BoardTileManeger_tileWallingTextures") as? Int {
        self.tileWallingTextures = TileWallTextures(type: WallType(rawValue: data)!)
    }

    }
```

The problem is, when decoding, all the data objects are nil. However, if I check whether there is a value for the keys, it returns true. Running breakpoints, the encode function and the required init are being called. Why is my data nil then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this issue, I spent the better part of a day figuring it out and found no luck. However, I figured out that the larger issue was found in my SKScene. My custom class was encoded and decoded as part of the scene. The solution was to use `NSKeyedArchiver` on my scene as follows:

```
override func encodeRestorableState(with coder: NSCoder) {
    self.sceneWasSaved = true
    if self.gameState != nil {
        coder.encode(self.sceneWasSaved, forKey: "GameViewController_sceneWasSaved")
        coder.encode(self.gameState!, forKey: "GameViewController_gameState")
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.gameScene!, toFile: filePath)
    }
    super.encodeRestorableState(with: coder)
}
```

Then unarchive:

```
vc.gameScene = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? GameScene
```

It seems that if we use the `coder` and `decoder` that `Spritekit` types are not properly handled for whatever odd reason. But if you use the archiver method it handles them and both my `SKScene` and my custom class was properly encoded and decoded.

Note I changed nothing in my custom class described in the question, only the archiving of `SKScene`.

Anyway, I don't have an answer of why this works, but maybe it will save someone!